# How are WiFi or Bluetooth drivers affected by suspending or hibernating?

Tags: linux, wifi, drivers, power-management, hibernate

I was reading about power management in Fedora when I stumbled upon this

> When a system is suspended, the kernel calls on drivers to store their
> states and then unloads them. When the system is resumed, it reloads
> these drivers, which attempt to reprogram their devices. The drivers'
> ability to accomplish this task determines whether the system can be
> resumed successfully.

So the wifi and other things are not in the ON state as they are 'unloaded' from the RAM (correct me if I am wrong). Can someone explain me in more detail what is meant by unloading the drivers? I read that the difference between hibernate and suspend is that the in hibernation everything is written to disk in order to resume the system from where it was. But what about the drivers? How are the two cases different from wifi and Bluetooth perspective?

Comment: Hibernate writes everything to swap, it needs to be on persistent-storage (e.g. Hard disk) to work. Suspend to RAM, writes to RAM, and needs some power to work.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between wifi and bluetooth (in the situation of hibernation or suspend) will be just in implementation detail: Does one have a bug, so that it can not be resumed.